# How can i open h264 video files in virtualdub?

Tags: h.264

First the video files was mp4 then i converted them to avi files.
Now that they are avi files when i try to open a video file in virtualdub i'm getting this error:

[image: VirtualDub Error]

Couldn't locat decompressor for format h264 (unknown) virtualdub requires video for windows vfw compaitable decompress ...etc

What i did so far ?

Install ffdshow in configuration i changed not to disable h264 and all others in decoder.

I installed divx

I have virtualdub 1.10.4
Now i'm using ffdshow 32bit i tried 64bit before

I have windows 8.1 pro 64bit

Tried almost or anything i found in google nothing worked so far.
I wanted to open the original mp4 video files in virtualdub but nothing worked so i converted it to avi but also not working.

What else can i do ?
Maybe there is another program like virtualdub that it will work ?

Answer (score 10):

You need to install the h.264 VFW codec here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/x264vfw/
Just close VirtualDub beforehand, and pick the default options in the installer. Worked like a charm for me.

AFAIK the file being MP4 or AVI is unimportant, it's just a change of "container", ie. what's inside both files is a h.264 encoded video channel.

Caveat: as mentioned by Ivo Kostić in another answer, it doesn't work well with interlaced x264 (I have no experience with that, I just thought this important fact should also appear in the "top" answer).

Comment: This should be marked as answer, the only way to make it work

Answer (score 3):

I used the [VirtualDub FFmpeg Input Driver Plugin](http://codecpack.co/download/FFInputDriver.html), [Direct sourcforge page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/virtualdubffmpeginputplugin/)

1. Download
2. Copy files to the plugins folders in the virtualdub directory
3. Restarted virtualdub

Answer (score -1):

and no matter what you do currently x264vfw (either as standalone as mentioned by ghis, or via ffdshow's vfw config (decoder options)) doesn't work well with interlaced h264, it doubles the framerate and then it's not really usable esp. if you just wanna cut video in 'direct stream copy mode'.

a bug that probably won't be fixed.

Comment: do you have a reference for this ?

Comment: This is more appropriate as a comment.  It does not answer the question.

Comment: tom, there is no definite answer, interlaced avc (video source can be laced or progressive) cannot be loaded to vdub properly. sheryl, you mean my experience with vdub since year 2000 and extensive work with its developers on solving bugs and making new plugins? well, yeah i have that. but i have 0 experience with comment vs. answers here, so i'll put it into comments.  edit/ oh wait, i won't because i can't, i need repuatation! heh....catch22.    btw. last sentence of ghis reply is not strictly correct, but i won't go into details, because comment police might get me! <wink>

Comment: btw. you can try it if you wish, i can provide you with interlaced avc sources, if you think i'm writing without trying it.